# Xcode 8 how to add single auto layout constraint without losing best guess layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode8

I'm wondering if anyone has insight to the auto layout differences between Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 in the following regard:

Imagine I only have one single view in the middle of the screen.

In both Xcode 7 and 8, if I had no constraints at all to this view the IB does a reasonable job at coming up with a position and size for the view.

Now I add just one constraint to center the view horizontally in the superview.

In Xcode 7 the view adheres to this one constraint and then does a best guess on the rest.  It's actually very close.

In Xcode 8, as soon as any one constraint is applied everything else goes out the window.  The view now has a completely wrong width and Y position.

Does anyone know how I can get similar functionality to what I had in Xcode 7?  There are situations where I only want to apply a single constraint and have auto layout give a best guess on the rest, not just completely give up.

Additionally, I did try to set the Interface Builder Document version to 7.x, but every time I reopen the storyboard it makes me choose a device size and resets to version 8.0